# Concatenate signs, find text in Word doc and Range.MoveEndUntil Cset:= paragraph sign & "2" & ". "

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have this macro that is run from Excel VBA editor and it searches strings in Word document, copies that string and pastes it into a cell in .Activesheet.Range("E27")

So I have this code and I'm already so close to making it work, but I need to concatenate four characters to make it work, paragraph sign (¶), & "2" & ". "

```
Sub AdjusFindFirstName()
    Sub AdjFindFirstName()
    'Variables declaration
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim Rng As Word.Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TextToFind As String
    Dim ApartmentPrice As String
    Dim StartPos As Long
    Dim EndPos As Long
    Dim FullName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Assigning object variables
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    'Searching
    With Rng.Find
    '.Text = TextToFind
    .Text = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"
    .Execute    '?Rng = REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,
        If .Found = True Then
            Rng.MoveEndUntil Cset:="2" & ". "  'expands Rng variable until first "2. "                  
            Rng.MoveEnd wdWord, 3          'expands Rng variable wdWord, 3 further
                                           'wdParagraph, wdLine, wdSentence, wdScreen
            If Rng.Words.Last.Next.Text = "-" Then    'I want the text of the word following the last word in my range
               Rng.MoveEnd wdWord, 2    'expands Rng variable wdWord, 2 further
            End If
            StartPos = InStr(1, Rng.Text, "2. ")
            FullName = Mid(Rng.Text, StartPos + 3)
        End If
    End With
    Debug.Print FullName
End Sub
```

In fact I cannot even execute `Range.MoveEndUntil Cset:= "2. "`

I even tried `Range.MoveEndUntil Cset:= "2" & ". "`

These lines are not expanding my `Rng` variable by any word or character.

But what I really need  is finding/MovingEndUntill `Cset:= "¶" & "2" & ". "`

Here is the printscreen, where I've selected the string I need to .MoveEndUntil

[image]

Maybe you could tell me how to expand my `Rng` variable until the end of the current paragraph?

Comment: ¶ is not a "real" character, it is just used to visualize the end of paragraph which is a non printable character (paragraph mark). It can be shown/hidden with CTRL+8. The paragraph mark can be found using the character sequence ^p in the Advanced Find, but you will need the special constant `vbCrLf` to find it using `MoveEndUntil`. BTW, MoveEndUntil will stop if it find any of the supplied character, not if the full sequence is found.

Comment: No @VincentG  `vbCrLf` is *incorrect* in Word. That's Chr(13) & Chr(10) which Word does not recognize correctly. Word uses ***only*** Chr(13) / `vbCr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful reading of the Help topic for `MoveEndUntil` reveals that it looks only at individual characters, not character combinations:

> Moves the end position of the specified range ***until any*** of the specified characters are found in the document.

There is no "Move" method that works in that manner. Word's `Find` feature, however, can locate character combinations. Adding an additional `Find` that runs from the first "found" term locates the information specified in the question. For example

```
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim rngStart As Word.Range, rngEnd As Word.Range

Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument
Set rngStart = WordDoc.Content
'Searching
With rngStart.Find
'.Text = TextToFind
    .Text = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"
    .Execute    '?Rng = REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,
    If .found = True Then
        'Instantiate a Range for the next search, starting with the first "found"
        Set rngEnd = rngStart.Duplicate
        'Extend that range to the end of the document
        rngEnd.End = WordDoc.Content.End
        With rngEnd.Find
            .Text = vbCr & "2. "
            .Forward = True
            .Execute
            If .found Then
                rngEnd.MoveEnd wdWord, 3
                If rngEnd.Words.Last.Next.Text = "-" Then    'I want the text of the word following the last word in my range
                    rng.MoveEnd wdWord, 2    'expands Rng variable wdWord, 2 further
                End If
            End If
        End With

        startPos = InStr(1, rngEnd.Text, "2. ")
        FullName = Mid(rngEnd.Text, startPos + 3)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Smart to duplicate the range and adjust the end, I learned a new trick today.

Comment: @jclasley In case `Range.Duplicate` is new to you, this is used to "copy" a `Range` object. If `rng2 = rng1` were used, it's a *deep copy*: both `Ranges` are (and remain) the exact same thing, so changing a property of one also changes the other. (This is the only thing in Word that behaves in that manner.) So if a copy is needed for separate manipulation, the `Duplicate` property is used.

Comment: I've used `.Duplicate` before, as well as an equality. It's interesting that they're deep copies, though not surprising. My intuition says that it's becasuse ranges are essentially a space representation anchored at two points, and you're declaring that `rng2` is "anchored" to `rng1`. Makes sense that any changes to `rng1` affect `rng2` since `rng2` is anchored to `rng1`s start and end.